# Find all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying the congruence equation $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let $x-1= 5m$ where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$

let $m= n+1$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

$$x-1= 5(n+1)$$

$$x-1 = 5n+5$$

$$x = 5n+6$$

---

This is what I have so far.  I am not sure if this is correct or if I'm on the right track.

Comment: What is the question exactly? $x \equiv 1 \mod 5$ if and only if $x = 1 + 5m$ for some integer $m$ so .... that is the answer.  The solutions are all $x$ so that $x = 1 + 5m$ for any $m \in \mathbb Z$.  There's nothing more to it.  Which *is* the same answer as $x = 5n + 6$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$.  I'm a bit puzzled why you added $1$ to $m$ though.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine but actually you could have just written $x = 5m+1$ where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

$$\{ x \in \mathbb{Z}: x \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \} = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z}: \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}, x=5m+ 1  \}$$

While it is not wrong, letting $m=n+1$ doesn't really simplify things.